# RstudioでExcelファイルを読み込もうとしてもエラーになります。

Tags: rstudio

```
install.packages('openxlsx')
library(openxlsx)  
X <- read.xlsx("data6.xlsx")
```

```
>X <- read.xlsx("data6.xlsx")
Error in read.xlsx("data6.xlsx") : could not find function "read.xlsx"
```

Comment: 一応これらの記事 [【Rで使える小技】RでExcel（xlsxファイル）を読み込む方法](https://datumstudio.jp/blog/r%E3%81%A7excel%EF%BC%88xlsx%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%EF%BC%89%E3%82%92%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%82%80/), [Rで解析：エクセルファイルの作成が大変便利！！「openxlsx」パッケージ](https://www.karada-good.net/analyticsr/r-535/), [【R言語】openxlsxを使ったエクセルファイルの入力・出力](https://multivariate-statistics.com/2021/12/07/r-programming-xlsx-files/) のとおりの事が行われているようなので、質問に記述された内容ではおかしなところは無さそうです。その場合は何が問題であるのか推測するのも難しいのでは？ 何かモジュールとかその版数一覧みたいな情報が追記されると良いかもしれません。